# How to add tracking numbers to orders and shipping confirmation emails in joomla2.5 with virtuemart2.0.16

Tags: joomla2.5, virtuemart

How to add tracking numbers to orders and shipping confirmation emails in joomla2.5 with virtuemart2.0.16 ?
Please specify in detail.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to add tracking numbers to your orders you must have a shipping provider. This provider must give you certain credentials to access the providers site to manage these orders. Also you have to develop a web-service which connects to the providers site sending the order information while a the same time retrieving the information wanted.

This is not a lot of help as to do this its not something of a couple of hours but hopefully this information gets you on the right track.

Regards.